Adding a new row to each group's last row in a dataframe
My original dataframe is as below:
List = [['2024-05-25', 'Group 1', 'Year 1', 23466882], ['2024-05-25', 'Group 1', 'Year 2', 458397284], ['2024-05-25', 'Group 1', 'Year 3', 2344545], ['2024-05-25', 'Group 2', 'Year 1', 6662345], ['2024-05-25', 'Group 2', 'Year 2', 46342], ['2024-05-25', 'Group 3', 'Year 1', 34234], ['2024-05-25', 'Group 3', 'Year 2', 45222]]
df = pd.DataFrame(List, columns = ['Report_date', 'Product_group', 'Year', 'Sales'])


For each product group, if "Year 3" does not exist, a new row with sales of 11 000 should be added to the end.
The output should look like this:

My initial idea is to split the dataframe into each product group and add a new row if the sub- dataframe does not have any info for Year 3 but that approach does not seem to be optimal.
Any comment is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Report Date is always same?

Do you need same Years for each groups like solutions in dupes?

Many thanks :D the below solution is exactly the same to what I expect

If need only add missing Year Year 3 for each group use pd.concat with filtered rows with first non exist groups with added new Year and Sales values:
Notice: This solution only added new rows for not exist Year 3, also working if not exist same years for any group. E.g. if remove first row, so Year 1 is missing.
g = df.loc[df['Year'].eq('Year 3'), 'Product_group']

out = (pd.concat([df, 
                  df.loc[~df['Product_group'].isin(g)]
                    .drop_duplicates('Product_group').assign(Year='Year 3', Sales=11000)])
          .sort_values(['Product_group','Year'], ignore_index=True))
print (out)
  Report_date Product_group    Year      Sales
0  2024-05-25       Group 1  Year 1   23466882
1  2024-05-25       Group 1  Year 2  458397284
2  2024-05-25       Group 1  Year 3    2344545
3  2024-05-25       Group 2  Year 1    6662345
4  2024-05-25       Group 2  Year 2      46342
5  2024-05-25       Group 2  Year 3      11000
6  2024-05-25       Group 3  Year 1      34234
7  2024-05-25       Group 3  Year 2      45222
8  2024-05-25       Group 3  Year 3      11000

